# How to expand a variable on console/shell prompt

Tags: readline

How do we expand a variable, ie. a '$' preceded name, to its value content on bash readline ?

Comment: That is a very peculiar use-case. Could you elaborate, where this would be useful? Maybe there are valid alternatives for what you are trying. Maybe you rather want to use `envsubsts` on the variable instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specifically mention readline, I think you want something so that this:

```
$ echo $foo
```

becomes:

```
$ echo bar
```

where `bar` is the value of `$foo`.

There is [this readline expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands):

> `shell-expand-line (M-C-e)`
>
> Expand the line as the
> shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all
> of the shell word expansions (see [Shell
> Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)).

`M-C-e` would typically be <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

However, this also expands everything else, like command substitutions, arithmetic expansion, etc.. So this:

```
$ echo $SHELL $(date) $((11+22))
```

becomes:

```
$ echo /bin/zsh Wed 3 Nov 00:52:09 JST 2021 33
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly your question but you can print a variable using [echo](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT_VALUE="default-value"
read -e -p $'\e[33mEnter variable name\e[0m: ' -i "$DEFAULT_VALUE" NEW_VAR
echo "New value for variable is: $NEW_VAR"
```

Comment: Some additional information explaining the ANSI escape sequences and the `read` command would be useful since they're outside of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would not know of any way to expand a variable during `read`, but you may evaluate it afterwards without changing the result if the stored sting is not referring to a variable name:

```
read -e variable
$SHELL

echo $valiable
$SHELL

eval echo $variable
/bin/bash

echo $variable | envsubst
/bin/bash

read -e n
hello

echo $n
hello

eval echo $n
hello

echo $n | envsubst
hello
```

Be aware of the dangers `eval` might have as it also runs any commands stored as variable. For security reasons, I'd thus strongly suggest sticking to `envsubst`.